# Accessing unique value pairs from an array without repeating myself

Tags: php, arrays, math, permutation

I am trying to access **unique** value pairs from an array in a random order - without repeating myself until I have to.

For example, if I have an array set A,B,C,D (generally an even number of items, but up to 20) then the first time through I might pair A-B & C-D. But I want to guarantee that the next time I do it, I avoid repeating my pairing and that I get both A-C & B-D and A-D and B-C before I then get A-B and C-D again. Each item should only be called once in each round.

I started off by shuffling the order of the array randomly then pairing two values together - but I need a way to prevent some pairings from occurring more frequently than others (ideally I'd want them to increment equally all the way through).

So I've moved to looking at permutations - and have managed to get a full array containing all the possible pairings using the code below:

```
    $this->items = array('A','B','C','D');

    $input = $this->items;
    $input_copy = $input;
    $output = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($input as $val) {

        $j = 0;
        foreach($input_copy as $cval) {
            if($j == $i) break;
            print $val.'-'.$cval.'<br/>';
            //$output[] = array($val => $cval);
            $j++;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    //print_r($output);
```

e.g for A, B, C, D I get:

```
b-a
c-a
c-b
d-a
d-b
d-c
```

I want to cycle through the set n-1 times and capture the results in another array, but I'm not sure how to generate the actual order from these unique options

In other words, I want to turn the list above in to the below:

```
1st run =>
    1=> A-B, 
    2=> C-D, 
2nd run =>
    1=> A-C, 
    2=> B-D,
3rd run =>
    1=> A-D, 
    2=> C-B,
```

It may be that I can do this more simply from $this->items. I've also had a look at the Math_Combinatorics PEAR package, but I wasn't sure where to start.

I'd be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [round-robin tournament algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)

```
Place elements in two rows. 
Fix one element - in this case A
For next round shift all other elements in circular manner. 
Pair them. 
Repeat N-1 times

A B
D C
-----
A D
C B
----
A C
B D
----
```

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP wants not only each possible pair to occur once, but each possible pairing. See my answer for comparison.

Comment: Actually, this looks like it might work. I'm trying it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Simeon I don't understand how to approve your correction (you are right, my flaw), so I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to generate each *pairing* exactly once, i.e. each partition of your whole sequence into pairs. If you only want each pair exactly once, that's a different problem handled in a different answer.

Think about this problem recursively: At the beginning you have *n* elements. From these, take the first and choose a partner for it from the remaining *n*-1 elements. Take this pair out of the list and recuse with the remaining *n*-2 elements. If you make each choice unbiased, the remaining pairing will be unbiased as well. But that doesn't guarantee you won't repeat yourself earlier than neccessary.

If you really want to be sure you avoid repeating pairings, you should first think about how many possible pairings there are. For now I'll assume that *n* is even, so you only have complete pairs. It's easy to adjust this to odd *n* with one unpaired element. To obtain the total number of possible pairings, you have to multiply your choices:

```
m=(n-1)*(n-3)*(n-5)*...*7*5*3*1
```

So it's a product of odd numbers. That's [A001147](http://oeis.org/A001147), also written as a [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) *m*=(*n*-1)!!. Note that these numbers grow fairly quickly, so even for moderate *n* (like *n*=16) you might not have to worry about repeating yourself simply because there are so many possible pairings to choose from that a repetition is fairly unlikely.

If you really want to be *sure* that you avoid repetitions, you could of course simply generate the whole list and shuffle it. But as I just indicated, that list could become *huge* as well. So instead I'd suggest you divide this problem into two steps. Find a way to generate all numbers from 0 to *m*-1 each exactly once, and find a way to turn such numbers into pairings. For the latter, you can simply decompose your number step by step. At each step, take `index % (n-1)` to make the current choice, and choose `(int)(index / (n-1))` as the index for subsequent choices in the recursive calls.

For the former, the easiest thing I can think of would be using a PRNG with a prime number *p*>*m* as its period. Using modular arithmetic, that should be easy to do. Then simply discard all values which are greater or equal to *m*. Discarding means that you skip to the next element in the sequence. This will give all pairings in an order which should *seem* fairly random. If the starting point in that sequence should be random, be sure that if you at first choose a value which is to be discarded, then you have to initialize again, not skip to the next element. Otherwise some elements would be more likely as starting points than others.