# Sets of all disjoint pairs

Tags: c, algorithm, set, permutation

Given a set `{1,2,3,4,5...n}` of `n` elements, we need to find all sets of disjoint pairs.

For example, if n=4, the output would be

```
{(1,2),(3,4)},   {(1,3),(2,4)},   {(1,4),(2,3)}
```

I am not even able to figure out how to start. I am hoping someone can give me a suggestion about which algorithm to use, and possibly some implementation details as well.

Comment: Give an example for small n value..

Comment: if n=4 , output would be {(1,2), (3,4)}, {(1,3),(2,4)},{(1,4),(2,3)}

Comment: we can give you an *idea*, not the whole algorithm or implementation.

Comment: yes, even an idea will be helpful

Comment: We *can* give anything any one person decides to give. Since the question is off-topic for this site (absent a given algorithm, it's really a math problem), chances of a good treatment are slim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
 Delphi code for recursive generation of (n-1)!! sets (1*3*5*7...n-1) from n=2*k elements

```
var
  A: TArray<Integer>;

  procedure Swap(i, j: integer);
  var
    t : integer;
  begin
    t := A[i];
    A[i] := A[j];
    A[j] := t;
  end;

  procedure MakePairs(Start: Integer; Pairs: string);
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    if Start >= Length(A) then
      Writeln(Pairs)
    else
    for i := Start + 1 to High(A) do begin
      Swap(Start + 1, i); //store used element in the array beginning
      MakePairs(Start + 2, Pairs + Format('(%d,%d)', [A[Start], A[Start + 1]]));
      Swap(Start + 1, i); //get it back
    end;
  end;

begin
  A := TArray<Integer>.Create(1,2,3,4,5,6);
  //be sure that array length is even!!!
  MakePairs(0, '');
  Writeln(PairCount);
```

Output:

```
(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)
(1,2)(3,5)(4,6)
(1,2)(3,6)(5,4)
(1,3)(2,4)(5,6)
(1,3)(2,5)(4,6)
(1,3)(2,6)(5,4)
(1,4)(3,2)(5,6)
(1,4)(3,5)(2,6)
(1,4)(3,6)(5,2)
(1,5)(3,4)(2,6)
(1,5)(3,2)(4,6)
(1,5)(3,6)(2,4)
(1,6)(3,4)(5,2)
(1,6)(3,5)(4,2)
(1,6)(3,2)(5,4)
15
```

**Addition**
Variant that works with odd-length array too (weird ordering)

```
  procedure MakePairs(Start: Integer; Pairs: string);
  var
    i: Integer;
    OddFlag: Integer;
  begin
    if Start >= Length(A) then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Pairs)
    else begin
      Oddflag := (High(A) - Start) and 1;
      for i := Start + OddFlag to High(A) do begin
        Swap(Start + OddFlag, i);
        if OddFlag = 1 then
          MakePairs(Start + 2, Pairs + Format('(%d,%d)', [A[Start], A[Start + 1]]))
        else
          MakePairs(Start + 1, Pairs);
        Swap(Start + OddFlag, i);
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

for (1,2,3,4,5):

```
(2,3)(4,5)
(2,4)(3,5)
(2,5)(4,3)
(1,3)(4,5)
(1,4)(3,5)
(1,5)(4,3)
(2,1)(4,5)
(2,4)(1,5)
(2,5)(4,1)
(2,3)(1,5)
(2,1)(3,5)
(2,5)(1,3)
(2,3)(4,1)
(2,4)(3,1)
(2,1)(4,3)
15
```

Not relevant now:
*If every pair should occur just once (it is not clear from your example with n=4), then you can use [round-robin tournament algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)*

*[n=4 case example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27439398/844416)*

Comment: no every pair is not occuring only once for {1,2,3,4,5,6} output will be {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)},{(1,3),(2,4),(5,6)},{(1,4),(2,3),(5,6)},{(1,2)(3,5)(4,6)} and so on... every element of one set has to pair with every element of other set

Comment: Aw, you skipped the fun part where `n` is odd, e.g. the output for `n=5` is (12)(34),(12)(35),(12)(45),(13)(24),(13)(25),(13)(45),(14)(23),(14)(25),(14)(35),(15)(23),(15)(24),(15)(34),(23)(45),(24)(35),(25)(34)

Comment: @user3386109  I wasn't sure that it is needed (leaving one element without pair)

Comment: Yup, it's debatable, the question wasn't very clear :)

Comment: @user3386109 added modification for that case

Comment: @MBo Great many thanks for your code! After porting it successfully to C, I have spent endless hours on an iterative version, but I am too much a beginner. Any idea where to find a solution?

Comment: @Niels Hagenbuch I posted recursive code because with this approach  I solved given problem in reasonable time :) Possible ways: emulate recursive algorithm with explicit stack (storing and retrieving task state); walking through numbers `0..(n-1)!!` - it is needed to invent a way to map number and specific pair set; come up with completely different approach - for example, enumerate "leading" elements in pairs (always 1 in the first pair and so on)

Answer (score 0):

You have to see the pattern here.

For `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

**Take the first element and make pairs with all the elements on the right.**

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)
```

**Take the second element and make pairs with all the elements on the right.**

```
(2, 3), (2, 4)
```

**Take the third element and make pairs with all the elements on the right.**

```
(3, 4)
```

**...and so on**

> Notice the pattern here.

---

**You would need an outer loop to iterate over the elements and select each element one by one.**

**And another inner loop to iterate over the elements on the right of the selected element and make a pair with each one of them.**

Comment: so are u asking me to notice the pattern like combining first and last pairs and then second and second last and so on.. like (1,2)(3,4); (1,3)(2,4);(1,4)(2,3) ?

Comment: @DiscoveringNew: The method described in this answer will find only the pairs, not disjoint sets of them.

Comment: @MOehm If the elements are distinct, it will find the disjoint pairs.

Comment: @haris: The elements are distinct by definition, but the desired output is not just the pairs, but sets of disjoint pairs as clarified by the OP in a comment to the question. (Maybe it's a good idea for the OP to edit the question accordingly.)

Comment: @MOehm ook. He needs to give an example then. Its a little confusing.

Comment: no it's not confusing the requirement is straight forward. I tried to add that example in the question itself but stackoverflow didn't allow :P

Comment: @DiscoveringNew You can edit your question and add the example. It should be allowed.