# Divisions of set with even number of elements

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Is there any effective way to list all divisions of a set `{1, ... , 2*n}` into `n` pairs?

The easiest idea is to list all permutations and then permutation `(a1, a2, ... , a8)` means division `{{a1,a2}, ... , {a7,a8}}`. In this situation there are `2^n * n!` permutations for each division. This is `O((2n)!)`.

Can I find a more effective way?

Comment: It's easy to enumerate the pairs.  If you allow the convention that you re-label the indexes to the lowest available values in order after "extracting" a pair, you get a flat (rather than tree) series of choices between kC2 items for k in (2*n down to 2 step 2).  You may then make the choices, descending down from 2*n to 2, and "read" the original indexes back up the chain, based on those choices.   The tradeoff is O(n) rather than O(1) selection time.  I'll put together some code later, perhaps, for an actual "answer", If no one beats me to it...

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately I don't understand your alghorithm. I will be grateful if you write some pseudo-code.

Comment: Does order matter? If you list all permutations, you'll get lots of `{{x,y}...}` listed separately from `{{y,x}...}` is that what you want?

Comment: Order inside of pair doesn't matter and order of pairs also doesn't. I want to find some way to list all divisions of {1,...,2*n} into two-element subsets. For example
1,2 - 3,4 - 5,6 - 7,8 is one division
2,1 - 3,4 - 5,6 - 7,8 is the same division
3,4 - 1,2 - 5,6 - 7,8 is also the same division.
The number of all divisions into "pairs" for the set {1,...2*n} is 
(2n-1)*(2n-3)*(2n-5)* ... *5*3*1 and I would like to list all of them in some effective way.

Comment: I know that list of all permutations isn't bijective with the list of all divisions, but there is an injection from permutations into divisions.

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493769/sets-of-all-disjoint-pairs/32494810#32494810

Answer (score 0):

Here's my pencil and paper algorithm:

```
f(set,result):
  if the set is empty:
    return result
  otherwise:
    pair one item from the set with
    each of the remaining items,
    calling f again with the pair added to
    the result and out of the set

123456
12 34 56
   35 46
   36 45
13 24 56
   25 46
   26 45
14 23 56
   25 36
   26 35
...
```